# Select an option in javascript and search for the paragraph

Tags: javascript

I want to make a simple html site which have some paragraphs and a drop-down list. When the site is loaded I want all the paragraphs to be inserted in the drop-down list (the first 50 characters for each option). When I choose an option, I want the paragraph of the chosen option to be bold and the page to scroll there. So far, I only did this. Please help! I want only in javascript.

```js
<script language="javascript">
        function add()
            {
                var x = document.getElementById("myselect");
                var pars = document.getElementsByTagName("P");
                for (i=0; i<pars.length; i++)
                    {
                        pars[i].setAttribute("class", "all_pars");
                        pars[i].setAttribute("value", "all_pars" + i);
                        var y = document.getElementsByClassName("all_pars")[i].innerHTML;
                        var option = document.createElement("option");
                        option.text = y;
                        x.add(option);
                    }
                
            }
        function dothis()
            {
                //var w = document.getElementById("myselect").selectedIndex;
                //w.scrollIntoView();
                var x = document.getElementById("myselect");
                var y = document.getElementById("myselect").options;
                
                
            }

    </script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="el">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Εργαστήριο 10 άσκηση 3</title>
</head>
<body onload="add()">
    <p>I am </p>
    <p>I am a dog</p>
    <p>I am a cat</p>
    <p>I am a bird</p>
    <p>I am </p>
    <p>I am a dog</p>
    <p>I am a cat</p>
    <p>I am a bird</p>
    <p>I am </p>
    <p>I am a dog</p>
    <p>I am a cat</p>
    <p>I am a bird</p>
    <select id="myselect" onchange="dothis()">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
    </select>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you want to find the good paragraph from your select. So you should find a way to link the paragraph to its select option.

```
for (i=0; i<pars.length; i++)
{
    pars[i].setAttribute("class", "all_pars");
    pars[i].setAttribute("id", "all_pars" + i);
    var y = document.getElementsByClassName("all_pars")[i].innerHTML;

    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = y.substring(0,50) + "..."; // Cutting the text in select to the first 50 characters
    option.value = "all_pars" + i
    x.add(option);
}
```

Here we go. We are now, rather than a value, choosing a id for each paragraph, and adding that id as a value to the linked select option. We are also cutting the paragraph down to 50 characters.

With this, it's easy to find the paragraph and change its style.

```
function dothis()
{
// Value indicating which paragraph should be chosen.
    var y = document.getElementById("myselect").value; 
    
    var pars = document.getElementsByTagName("P"); 
    for (i=0; i<pars.length; i++)
    {
 // Putting all paragraph to not-bold
        pars[i].setAttribute("style", "font-weight: normal;");
    }

    document.getElementById(y).setAttribute("style", "font-weight: bold;"); // Putting our paragraph to bold
}
```

Now we have our text in bold when we select it. We just have to add anchor to each paragraph and change the location to the anchor when we select the paragraph. Here is the final code, with lorem ipsum as paragraphs.

```js
function add()
            {
                var x = document.getElementById("myselect");
                var pars = document.getElementsByTagName("P");
                for (i=0; i<pars.length; i++)
                {

                    pars[i].setAttribute("class", "all_pars");
                    pars[i].setAttribute("id", "all_pars" + i);
                    var y = document.getElementsByClassName("all_pars")[i].innerHTML;

                    var option = document.createElement("option");
                    option.text = y.substring(0,50) + "..."; // Cutting the text in select to the first 50 characters
                    option.value = "all_pars" + i
                    x.add(option);

                    // Add anchor to the paragraph
                    var newLink = document.createElement('a'); 
                    newLink.name = "all_pars" + i;
                    pars[i].appendChild(newLink);
                }

                pars[0].setAttribute("style", "font-weight: bold;");
                
            }
    function dothis()
    {
        var x = document.getElementById("myselect");
        var y = document.getElementById("myselect").value; // Value indicating which paragraph should be chosen.
        
        var pars = document.getElementsByTagName("P"); 
        for (i=0; i<pars.length; i++)
        {
            pars[i].setAttribute("style", "font-weight: normal;"); // Putting all paragraph to not-bold
        }

        document.getElementById(y).setAttribute("style", "font-weight: bold;"); // Putting our paragraph to bold

        window.location = '#' + y; // Jump to anchor
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="el">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Εργαστήριο 10 άσκηση 3</title>
    </head>
    <body onload="add()">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus tortor orci, euismod a ante et, iaculis malesuada nulla. Praesent pellentesque hendrerit urna, a posuere magna facilisis eu. Vestibulum iaculis fringilla orci, vel rutrum felis mollis eu. Proin pretium et nunc eget ullamcorper. Praesent vel nisi eleifend, facilisis sapien nec, malesuada diam. Phasellus nibh justo, auctor et suscipit eget, aliquam sed lacus. Etiam odio libero, convallis vitae ultricies ac, interdum ut dolor. Etiam ullamcorper orci a sem feugiat porttitor. Proin sit amet pellentesque velit, non molestie nisi. Morbi at pellentesque urna, eu ultrices sapien. Nulla bibendum, dui sit amet finibus mollis, ipsum lacus dictum elit, id luctus turpis ligula ut nisi.</p>
        <p>Integer quis scelerisque turpis. Nam ornare erat sed nisi consequat tincidunt. Donec consectetur turpis dui. Quisque vel mi eget dolor volutpat scelerisque. Etiam sagittis justo tincidunt, posuere erat et, bibendum eros. Proin mattis lobortis purus in rutrum. Phasellus imperdiet ante nibh, ut maximus lacus facilisis et. Morbi non pretium est. Fusce a turpis auctor, cursus lectus at, hendrerit erat. Praesent sit amet lacus id risus ornare pharetra at at odio. Aliquam a vehicula orci.</p>
        <p>Cras imperdiet orci quis est scelerisque, ac bibendum dui dapibus. Etiam ullamcorper elit vitae felis blandit mollis. Morbi est libero, feugiat at justo vitae, interdum interdum erat. Donec tincidunt nibh a sagittis imperdiet. Fusce in libero nec libero iaculis aliquet eget sit amet ante. Nulla velit diam, congue vitae malesuada quis, posuere eget leo. Pellentesque quis interdum turpis. Curabitur ut risus bibendum, finibus nibh ut, ultrices metus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean at egestas ipsum, et lobortis quam. Etiam mattis arcu mollis porta molestie. Vestibulum sollicitudin ipsum mauris, ut efficitur elit bibendum in.</p>
        <p>Integer sed vehicula est, vitae venenatis felis. Suspendisse nisl risus, convallis sit amet varius non, elementum eu dolor. Pellentesque sem erat, venenatis a justo id, dictum dapibus nisl. In accumsan dapibus elementum. Nunc viverra, nisl in rhoncus aliquam, turpis ligula aliquet mauris, at imperdiet quam diam at metus. Etiam et erat elit. Phasellus in tortor eu erat pulvinar facilisis.</p>
        <p>Integer finibus, diam eget volutpat maximus, erat nunc suscipit nisi, et scelerisque augue ligula ultrices quam. Nulla eget ipsum tristique, bibendum mauris ac, sollicitudin quam. Quisque lacinia, sapien quis faucibus tincidunt, mi orci volutpat lorem, sed commodo quam sapien vehicula lectus. Aliquam pharetra felis ut arcu auctor, vitae rhoncus felis placerat. Pellentesque finibus sem vitae imperdiet pharetra. Quisque pulvinar viverra mauris sed accumsan. Mauris feugiat, eros vitae facilisis lobortis, ipsum neque gravida massa, at dictum mauris odio non odio. Integer nec leo urna. Pellentesque tempus lacus at elementum tincidunt. Sed cursus velit eros, nec placerat ante convallis at. Nullam sed dictum ex, a pretium lacus. Integer vitae pellentesque augue, vel efficitur tortor. Vivamus sit amet vestibulum nulla, eget porta ante. Integer sed nulla id eros pharetra dignissim. Sed orci massa, facilisis ac porttitor id, fermentum eu augue.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus tortor orci, euismod a ante et, iaculis malesuada nulla. Praesent pellentesque hendrerit urna, a posuere magna facilisis eu. Vestibulum iaculis fringilla orci, vel rutrum felis mollis eu. Proin pretium et nunc eget ullamcorper. Praesent vel nisi eleifend, facilisis sapien nec, malesuada diam. Phasellus nibh justo, auctor et suscipit eget, aliquam sed lacus. Etiam odio libero, convallis vitae ultricies ac, interdum ut dolor. Etiam ullamcorper orci a sem feugiat porttitor. Proin sit amet pellentesque velit, non molestie nisi. Morbi at pellentesque urna, eu ultrices sapien. Nulla bibendum, dui sit amet finibus mollis, ipsum lacus dictum elit, id luctus turpis ligula ut nisi.</p>
        <p>Integer quis scelerisque turpis. Nam ornare erat sed nisi consequat tincidunt. Donec consectetur turpis dui. Quisque vel mi eget dolor volutpat scelerisque. Etiam sagittis justo tincidunt, posuere erat et, bibendum eros. Proin mattis lobortis purus in rutrum. Phasellus imperdiet ante nibh, ut maximus lacus facilisis et. Morbi non pretium est. Fusce a turpis auctor, cursus lectus at, hendrerit erat. Praesent sit amet lacus id risus ornare pharetra at at odio. Aliquam a vehicula orci.</p>
        <p>Cras imperdiet orci quis est scelerisque, ac bibendum dui dapibus. Etiam ullamcorper elit vitae felis blandit mollis. Morbi est libero, feugiat at justo vitae, interdum interdum erat. Donec tincidunt nibh a sagittis imperdiet. Fusce in libero nec libero iaculis aliquet eget sit amet ante. Nulla velit diam, congue vitae malesuada quis, posuere eget leo. Pellentesque quis interdum turpis. Curabitur ut risus bibendum, finibus nibh ut, ultrices metus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean at egestas ipsum, et lobortis quam. Etiam mattis arcu mollis porta molestie. Vestibulum sollicitudin ipsum mauris, ut efficitur elit bibendum in.</p>
        <p>Integer sed vehicula est, vitae venenatis felis. Suspendisse nisl risus, convallis sit amet varius non, elementum eu dolor. Pellentesque sem erat, venenatis a justo id, dictum dapibus nisl. In accumsan dapibus elementum. Nunc viverra, nisl in rhoncus aliquam, turpis ligula aliquet mauris, at imperdiet quam diam at metus. Etiam et erat elit. Phasellus in tortor eu erat pulvinar facilisis.</p>
        <p>Duis viverra sollicitudin euismod. Maecenas rhoncus neque vel purus aliquam pellentesque. Praesent quis lobortis tellus. Ut sit amet tempor magna. Aliquam accumsan magna vel efficitur rutrum. Aliquam a leo quam. Quisque urna sem, finibus cursus vehicula sit amet, facilisis vitae metus. Proin commodo lorem in maximus posuere. Mauris vel eros cursus, blandit sapien et, ultrices lorem. Donec ultricies nisi at neque congue, eu dictum ipsum volutpat. Donec lacinia lacinia interdum. Nam at posuere neque. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum fermentum commodo eleifend. Nullam ut sem magna.</p>
        <p>Cras interdum maximus rhoncus. Donec erat metus, vestibulum vitae rhoncus nec, egestas at nunc. Sed porta at nulla sed eleifend. Aliquam accumsan eros justo, at ornare dui aliquet eget. Phasellus posuere sapien eu nunc venenatis, molestie scelerisque lorem vestibulum. Proin eu porta augue, at tempus arcu. In vitae porta leo. Ut scelerisque turpis nec massa euismod, quis lobortis diam tempus. Proin elementum sed mauris in elementum. Proin convallis nulla lectus, nec pellentesque purus consectetur sit amet. Sed gravida condimentum nibh ac interdum.</p>
        <p>Donec ut ligula at magna vehicula blandit vitae a justo. Aenean urna neque, egestas vitae velit ac, auctor gravida urna. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Sed pulvinar ac erat a faucibus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut consectetur sagittis lacinia. Donec feugiat lacus eu est semper bibendum. Suspendisse nec ultrices neque, eu suscipit est. Curabitur semper est vitae arcu consequat suscipit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vivamus pulvinar libero at arcu volutpat commodo at non sapien. Cras commodo erat sit amet blandit venenatis. Etiam tincidunt massa sit amet magna porttitor, aliquam egestas purus mollis. Aenean efficitur ante vitae augue gravida molestie.</p>
        <p>Etiam tincidunt ipsum sit amet posuere tristique. Donec molestie sapien orci. Ut accumsan consequat nisi, eget mattis eros. Duis venenatis nunc id ipsum ultricies, cursus tincidunt sapien dignissim. Maecenas mattis eros nibh. Pellentesque in lorem turpis. Phasellus euismod, mi sit amet posuere tincidunt, mi turpis varius lectus, id molestie quam mi ut est. Duis vel dui bibendum, pellentesque lacus at, molestie felis. Nulla facilisi. Nunc augue dui, tempor non turpis in, accumsan cursus felis. Suspendisse nisl orci, consectetur id augue in, fermentum finibus erat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum metus felis, tristique ut orci vel, posuere tincidunt tellus. Sed lacus augue, luctus a libero vel, molestie sollicitudin purus. Nam euismod tortor id venenatis ullamcorper.</p>
        <p>Maecenas mattis sem id mauris commodo aliquam. Maecenas volutpat lectus dui, a vestibulum leo vehicula nec. Ut ac leo id odio bibendum imperdiet ut in lectus. Praesent nec felis at nibh maximus ullamcorper sed a turpis. Curabitur congue tincidunt bibendum. Fusce vulputate lorem eu massa aliquam vehicula. Suspendisse elementum justo ut venenatis tempor. Aliquam vel urna nec risus lacinia convallis consequat ut elit. Phasellus vel fringilla est. Vivamus a viverra tellus. Etiam gravida tempus turpis, eu finibus orci mollis at. Cras sit amet neque eu orci commodo ultrices.</p>
        <p>Integer finibus, diam eget volutpat maximus, erat nunc suscipit nisi, et scelerisque augue ligula ultrices quam. Nulla eget ipsum tristique, bibendum mauris ac, sollicitudin quam. Quisque lacinia, sapien quis faucibus tincidunt, mi orci volutpat lorem, sed commodo quam sapien vehicula lectus. Aliquam pharetra felis ut arcu auctor, vitae rhoncus felis placerat. Pellentesque finibus sem vitae imperdiet pharetra. Quisque pulvinar viverra mauris sed accumsan. Mauris feugiat, eros vitae facilisis lobortis, ipsum neque gravida massa, at dictum mauris odio non odio. Integer nec leo urna. Pellentesque tempus lacus at elementum tincidunt. Sed cursus velit eros, nec placerat ante convallis at. Nullam sed dictum ex, a pretium lacus. Integer vitae pellentesque augue, vel efficitur tortor. Vivamus sit amet vestibulum nulla, eget porta ante. Integer sed nulla id eros pharetra dignissim. Sed orci massa, facilisis ac porttitor id, fermentum eu augue.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus tortor orci, euismod a ante et, iaculis malesuada nulla. Praesent pellentesque hendrerit urna, a posuere magna facilisis eu. Vestibulum iaculis fringilla orci, vel rutrum felis mollis eu. Proin pretium et nunc eget ullamcorper. Praesent vel nisi eleifend, facilisis sapien nec, malesuada diam. Phasellus nibh justo, auctor et suscipit eget, aliquam sed lacus. Etiam odio libero, convallis vitae ultricies ac, interdum ut dolor. Etiam ullamcorper orci a sem feugiat porttitor. Proin sit amet pellentesque velit, non molestie nisi. Morbi at pellentesque urna, eu ultrices sapien. Nulla bibendum, dui sit amet finibus mollis, ipsum lacus dictum elit, id luctus turpis ligula ut nisi.</p>
        <p>Integer quis scelerisque turpis. Nam ornare erat sed nisi consequat tincidunt. Donec consectetur turpis dui. Quisque vel mi eget dolor volutpat scelerisque. Etiam sagittis justo tincidunt, posuere erat et, bibendum eros. Proin mattis lobortis purus in rutrum. Phasellus imperdiet ante nibh, ut maximus lacus facilisis et. Morbi non pretium est. Fusce a turpis auctor, cursus lectus at, hendrerit erat. Praesent sit amet lacus id risus ornare pharetra at at odio. Aliquam a vehicula orci.</p>
        <p>Cras imperdiet orci quis est scelerisque, ac bibendum dui dapibus. Etiam ullamcorper elit vitae felis blandit mollis. Morbi est libero, feugiat at justo vitae, interdum interdum erat. Donec tincidunt nibh a sagittis imperdiet. Fusce in libero nec libero iaculis aliquet eget sit amet ante. Nulla velit diam, congue vitae malesuada quis, posuere eget leo. Pellentesque quis interdum turpis. Curabitur ut risus bibendum, finibus nibh ut, ultrices metus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean at egestas ipsum, et lobortis quam. Etiam mattis arcu mollis porta molestie. Vestibulum sollicitudin ipsum mauris, ut efficitur elit bibendum in.</p>
        <p>Integer sed vehicula est, vitae venenatis felis. Suspendisse nisl risus, convallis sit amet varius non, elementum eu dolor. Pellentesque sem erat, venenatis a justo id, dictum dapibus nisl. In accumsan dapibus elementum. Nunc viverra, nisl in rhoncus aliquam, turpis ligula aliquet mauris, at imperdiet quam diam at metus. Etiam et erat elit. Phasellus in tortor eu erat pulvinar facilisis.</p>
        <p>Duis viverra sollicitudin euismod. Maecenas rhoncus neque vel purus aliquam pellentesque. Praesent quis lobortis tellus. Ut sit amet tempor magna. Aliquam accumsan magna vel efficitur rutrum. Aliquam a leo quam. Quisque urna sem, finibus cursus vehicula sit amet, facilisis vitae metus. Proin commodo lorem in maximus posuere. Mauris vel eros cursus, blandit sapien et, ultrices lorem. Donec ultricies nisi at neque congue, eu dictum ipsum volutpat. Donec lacinia lacinia interdum. Nam at posuere neque. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum fermentum commodo eleifend. Nullam ut sem magna.</p>
        <p>Cras interdum maximus rhoncus. Donec erat metus, vestibulum vitae rhoncus nec, egestas at nunc. Sed porta at nulla sed eleifend. Aliquam accumsan eros justo, at ornare dui aliquet eget. Phasellus posuere sapien eu nunc venenatis, molestie scelerisque lorem vestibulum. Proin eu porta augue, at tempus arcu. In vitae porta leo. Ut scelerisque turpis nec massa euismod, quis lobortis diam tempus. Proin elementum sed mauris in elementum. Proin convallis nulla lectus, nec pellentesque purus consectetur sit amet. Sed gravida condimentum nibh ac interdum.</p>
        <p>Donec ut ligula at magna vehicula blandit vitae a justo. Aenean urna neque, egestas vitae velit ac, auctor gravida urna. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Sed pulvinar ac erat a faucibus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut consectetur sagittis lacinia. Donec feugiat lacus eu est semper bibendum. Suspendisse nec ultrices neque, eu suscipit est. Curabitur semper est vitae arcu consequat suscipit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vivamus pulvinar libero at arcu volutpat commodo at non sapien. Cras commodo erat sit amet blandit venenatis. Etiam tincidunt massa sit amet magna porttitor, aliquam egestas purus mollis. Aenean efficitur ante vitae augue gravida molestie.</p>
        <p>Etiam tincidunt ipsum sit amet posuere tristique. Donec molestie sapien orci. Ut accumsan consequat nisi, eget mattis eros. Duis venenatis nunc id ipsum ultricies, cursus tincidunt sapien dignissim. Maecenas mattis eros nibh. Pellentesque in lorem turpis. Phasellus euismod, mi sit amet posuere tincidunt, mi turpis varius lectus, id molestie quam mi ut est. Duis vel dui bibendum, pellentesque lacus at, molestie felis. Nulla facilisi. Nunc augue dui, tempor non turpis in, accumsan cursus felis. Suspendisse nisl orci, consectetur id augue in, fermentum finibus erat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum metus felis, tristique ut orci vel, posuere tincidunt tellus. Sed lacus augue, luctus a libero vel, molestie sollicitudin purus. Nam euismod tortor id venenatis ullamcorper.</p>
        <p>Maecenas mattis sem id mauris commodo aliquam. Maecenas volutpat lectus dui, a vestibulum leo vehicula nec. Ut ac leo id odio bibendum imperdiet ut in lectus. Praesent nec felis at nibh maximus ullamcorper sed a turpis. Curabitur congue tincidunt bibendum. Fusce vulputate lorem eu massa aliquam vehicula. Suspendisse elementum justo ut venenatis tempor. Aliquam vel urna nec risus lacinia convallis consequat ut elit. Phasellus vel fringilla est. Vivamus a viverra tellus. Etiam gravida tempus turpis, eu finibus orci mollis at. Cras sit amet neque eu orci commodo ultrices.</p>
        <p>Integer finibus, diam eget volutpat maximus, erat nunc suscipit nisi, et scelerisque augue ligula ultrices quam. Nulla eget ipsum tristique, bibendum mauris ac, sollicitudin quam. Quisque lacinia, sapien quis faucibus tincidunt, mi orci volutpat lorem, sed commodo quam sapien vehicula lectus. Aliquam pharetra felis ut arcu auctor, vitae rhoncus felis placerat. Pellentesque finibus sem vitae imperdiet pharetra. Quisque pulvinar viverra mauris sed accumsan. Mauris feugiat, eros vitae facilisis lobortis, ipsum neque gravida massa, at dictum mauris odio non odio. Integer nec leo urna. Pellentesque tempus lacus at elementum tincidunt. Sed cursus velit eros, nec placerat ante convallis at. Nullam sed dictum ex, a pretium lacus. Integer vitae pellentesque augue, vel efficitur tortor. Vivamus sit amet vestibulum nulla, eget porta ante. Integer sed nulla id eros pharetra dignissim. Sed orci massa, facilisis ac porttitor id, fermentum eu augue.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus tortor orci, euismod a ante et, iaculis malesuada nulla. Praesent pellentesque hendrerit urna, a posuere magna facilisis eu. Vestibulum iaculis fringilla orci, vel rutrum felis mollis eu. Proin pretium et nunc eget ullamcorper. Praesent vel nisi eleifend, facilisis sapien nec, malesuada diam. Phasellus nibh justo, auctor et suscipit eget, aliquam sed lacus. Etiam odio libero, convallis vitae ultricies ac, interdum ut dolor. Etiam ullamcorper orci a sem feugiat porttitor. Proin sit amet pellentesque velit, non molestie nisi. Morbi at pellentesque urna, eu ultrices sapien. Nulla bibendum, dui sit amet finibus mollis, ipsum lacus dictum elit, id luctus turpis ligula ut nisi.</p>
        <p>Integer quis scelerisque turpis. Nam ornare erat sed nisi consequat tincidunt. Donec consectetur turpis dui. Quisque vel mi eget dolor volutpat scelerisque. Etiam sagittis justo tincidunt, posuere erat et, bibendum eros. Proin mattis lobortis purus in rutrum. Phasellus imperdiet ante nibh, ut maximus lacus facilisis et. Morbi non pretium est. Fusce a turpis auctor, cursus lectus at, hendrerit erat. Praesent sit amet lacus id risus ornare pharetra at at odio. Aliquam a vehicula orci.</p>
        <p>Cras imperdiet orci quis est scelerisque, ac bibendum dui dapibus. Etiam ullamcorper elit vitae felis blandit mollis. Morbi est libero, feugiat at justo vitae, interdum interdum erat. Donec tincidunt nibh a sagittis imperdiet. Fusce in libero nec libero iaculis aliquet eget sit amet ante. Nulla velit diam, congue vitae malesuada quis, posuere eget leo. Pellentesque quis interdum turpis. Curabitur ut risus bibendum, finibus nibh ut, ultrices metus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean at egestas ipsum, et lobortis quam. Etiam mattis arcu mollis porta molestie. Vestibulum sollicitudin ipsum mauris, ut efficitur elit bibendum in.</p>
        <p>Integer sed vehicula est, vitae venenatis felis. Suspendisse nisl risus, convallis sit amet varius non, elementum eu dolor. Pellentesque sem erat, venenatis a justo id, dictum dapibus nisl. In accumsan dapibus elementum. Nunc viverra, nisl in rhoncus aliquam, turpis ligula aliquet mauris, at imperdiet quam diam at metus. Etiam et erat elit. Phasellus in tortor eu erat pulvinar facilisis.</p>
        <p>Duis viverra sollicitudin euismod. Maecenas rhoncus neque vel purus aliquam pellentesque. Praesent quis lobortis tellus. Ut sit amet tempor magna. Aliquam accumsan magna vel efficitur rutrum. Aliquam a leo quam. Quisque urna sem, finibus cursus vehicula sit amet, facilisis vitae metus. Proin commodo lorem in maximus posuere. Mauris vel eros cursus, blandit sapien et, ultrices lorem. Donec ultricies nisi at neque congue, eu dictum ipsum volutpat. Donec lacinia lacinia interdum. Nam at posuere neque. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum fermentum commodo eleifend. Nullam ut sem magna.</p>
        <p>Cras interdum maximus rhoncus. Donec erat metus, vestibulum vitae rhoncus nec, egestas at nunc. Sed porta at nulla sed eleifend. Aliquam accumsan eros justo, at ornare dui aliquet eget. Phasellus posuere sapien eu nunc venenatis, molestie scelerisque lorem vestibulum. Proin eu porta augue, at tempus arcu. In vitae porta leo. Ut scelerisque turpis nec massa euismod, quis lobortis diam tempus. Proin elementum sed mauris in elementum. Proin convallis nulla lectus, nec pellentesque purus consectetur sit amet. Sed gravida condimentum nibh ac interdum.</p>
        <p>Donec ut ligula at magna vehicula blandit vitae a justo. Aenean urna neque, egestas vitae velit ac, auctor gravida urna. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Sed pulvinar ac erat a faucibus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut consectetur sagittis lacinia. Donec feugiat lacus eu est semper bibendum. Suspendisse nec ultrices neque, eu suscipit est. Curabitur semper est vitae arcu consequat suscipit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vivamus pulvinar libero at arcu volutpat commodo at non sapien. Cras commodo erat sit amet blandit venenatis. Etiam tincidunt massa sit amet magna porttitor, aliquam egestas purus mollis. Aenean efficitur ante vitae augue gravida molestie.</p>
        <p>Etiam tincidunt ipsum sit amet posuere tristique. Donec molestie sapien orci. Ut accumsan consequat nisi, eget mattis eros. Duis venenatis nunc id ipsum ultricies, cursus tincidunt sapien dignissim. Maecenas mattis eros nibh. Pellentesque in lorem turpis. Phasellus euismod, mi sit amet posuere tincidunt, mi turpis varius lectus, id molestie quam mi ut est. Duis vel dui bibendum, pellentesque lacus at, molestie felis. Nulla facilisi. Nunc augue dui, tempor non turpis in, accumsan cursus felis. Suspendisse nisl orci, consectetur id augue in, fermentum finibus erat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum metus felis, tristique ut orci vel, posuere tincidunt tellus. Sed lacus augue, luctus a libero vel, molestie sollicitudin purus. Nam euismod tortor id venenatis ullamcorper.</p>
        <p>Maecenas mattis sem id mauris commodo aliquam. Maecenas volutpat lectus dui, a vestibulum leo vehicula nec. Ut ac leo id odio bibendum imperdiet ut in lectus. Praesent nec felis at nibh maximus ullamcorper sed a turpis. Curabitur congue tincidunt bibendum. Fusce vulputate lorem eu massa aliquam vehicula. Suspendisse elementum justo ut venenatis tempor. Aliquam vel urna nec risus lacinia convallis consequat ut elit. Phasellus vel fringilla est. Vivamus a viverra tellus. Etiam gravida tempus turpis, eu finibus orci mollis at. Cras sit amet neque eu orci commodo ultrices.</p>
        <p>Integer finibus, diam eget volutpat maximus, erat nunc suscipit nisi, et scelerisque augue ligula ultrices quam. Nulla eget ipsum tristique, bibendum mauris ac, sollicitudin quam. Quisque lacinia, sapien quis faucibus tincidunt, mi orci volutpat lorem, sed commodo quam sapien vehicula lectus. Aliquam pharetra felis ut arcu auctor, vitae rhoncus felis placerat. Pellentesque finibus sem vitae imperdiet pharetra. Quisque pulvinar viverra mauris sed accumsan. Mauris feugiat, eros vitae facilisis lobortis, ipsum neque gravida massa, at dictum mauris odio non odio. Integer nec leo urna. Pellentesque tempus lacus at elementum tincidunt. Sed cursus velit eros, nec placerat ante convallis at. Nullam sed dictum ex, a pretium lacus. Integer vitae pellentesque augue, vel efficitur tortor. Vivamus sit amet vestibulum nulla, eget porta ante. Integer sed nulla id eros pharetra dignissim. Sed orci massa, facilisis ac porttitor id, fermentum eu augue.</p>

        <select id="myselect" onchange="dothis()">
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, my friend! I know that this is a simple project, but I couldn't do it. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to vote up the answer and confirm it as a good answer.

Comment: I tried it immediately, but it says to me: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."